# Invalid regular expression, Invalid group Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have  a C# code that check's for falseNumber on regex basis:

```
public bool falseNumber(string num)
    {
        try
        {
            num = num.Replace("-", "");
            string re = @"(?x)
            ^
            # fail if...
            (?!
                # repeating numbers
                (\d) \1+ $
                |
                # sequential ascending
                (?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){5} \d $
                |
                # sequential descending
                (?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5} \d $
            )
            # match any other combinations of 6 digits
            \d+
            $
        ";
            return Regex.IsMatch(num, re);
        }
        catch (Exception y) { return true; }
    }
```

I need this code to be converted to JS, so I have written:

```
const falseNumber = (num) =>
{
  num = num.replaceAll("-", "");
  let re = /(?x)^(?!(\d)\1+$|(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){5}\d$|(?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5}\d$)\d+$/
  return re.test(num);
}
```

But that gives me error:

> VM46:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
> /((?x)^(?!(\d) \1+
> $|(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){5} \d
> $|(?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5} \d $)\d+$)/: Invalid group
> at falseNumber (:5:12)
> at :1:1

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

```js
const falseNumber = (num) =>
{
  num = num.replaceAll("-", "");
  let re = /(?x)^(?!(\d)\1+$|(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){5}\d$|(?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5}\d$)\d+$/
  return re.test(num);
}


console.log(falseNumber('33-3333333-33'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` modifier is not built in JS that's why you get an error. And in your case, you don't need to use `x` modifier because you don't use comments or have any whitespace in your regex expression in JS.

`x` modifier definition:

> This flag tells the engine to ignore all whitespace and allow for
> comments in the regex; also called verbose. Comments are indicated by
> a starting "#"-character. If you need to include a space character in
> your regex, it must now be escaped '\ '.

```js
const falseNumber = (num) =>
{
  num = num.replaceAll("-", "");
  let re = /^(?!(\d)\1+$|(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0)){5}\d$|(?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5}\d$)\d+$/
  return re.test(num);
}


console.log(falseNumber('33-3333333-33'));
```